# role of the word (that)

Tags: grammar, pronouns, conjunctions

In this sentence

> During this paksha, Moon is ahead of sun by an amount *that* is between 0 and 180.

What is the grammatical role of the word "that" in the sentence?

Comment: "That is between 0 and 180" is a relative clause in which "that" is a subordinator' whose function is that of 'marker'.

Comment: When writing or speaking of the main day and night lights in the sky we use definite articles, and it is usual to capitalise, like this: write '**the** Moon' and '**the** Sun'.

Answer (score 1):

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that) says that as a ***pronoun***, ***that*** is

> used as a *function word* to introduce *a restrictive relative clause* and to serve as a substitute within that clause for the substantive modified by the clause
>
> - *the house* ***that*** Jack built

So in your sentence,

> *an amount* **that** is between 0 and 180

***that*** is a pronoun introducing the relative *that is between 0 and 180*, which modifies the noun *amount*. Within the relative, *that* replaces *amount*, being the subject of *is*.

Comment: Eh? It's not a pronoun but a subordinator -- the same one that introduces declarative content clauses.

Answer (score 1):

> *During this paksha, Moon is ahead of sun by an amount* [*that is between*
> *0 and 180*].

This is a relative construction. The bracketed expression, "that is between 0 and 180", is a relative clause in which "that" is a subordinator' whose function is that of 'marker'.

Note: despite what most dictionaries say, and what you may read on grammar websites (most of which are not authoritative sources) "that" is not a relative pronoun.

One dictionary gets it right: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/that)

Comment: Of course, simple wiktionary is not an "authoritative source" either.  In fact I'm not sure that there is such a thing for English!  There is no authority that defines what is correct grammar, only people with various levels of expertise.

Comment: @JamesK 1. I disagree. The latest and very best grammars are based on evidence and are compiled from a huge amount of data, descriptive not prescriptive, of course.  2. Actually, in most instances, Wiktionary is a good resource because it is compiled (mostly) by grammarians, including one famous one who shall remain nameless. 3. There is plenty of evidence to prove that relative "that" is a subordinator, not a pronoun. CGEL gives a number of them.